# Unable to connect to Mosquitto broker running on a Windows EC2 Instance from outside the EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I have a Mosquitto Broker running in a Windows EC2 Instance. I can connect to it using MQQTX, MQTT Explorer and MQTT JS library in NodeJS app with following credentials:

```
Protocol: mqtt
Host: localhost or 127.0.0.1
Port: 1883
Username: as defined in password.txt file
Password: as defined in password.txt file
```

What I need to do is connect to this broker from outside the EC2 Instance. I have tried adding port 1883 to EC2 instance inbound rules on AWS console and allowing all traffic in outbound rules. I even tried allowing all traffic in inbound rules.
I have also added port 1883 to Windows firewall inbound rules.

When I try to connect to this broker from outside using the Public IP/DNS/name of the EC2 instance, I can see that the request is coming in on port 1883 using Wireshark but it does not get acknowledged and the request times out.

I added 2 users to a `password.txt` file, encrypted them using `mosquitto_passwd -U password.txt` command. Added `allow_anonymous false` and `password_file C:\mosquitto\password.txt` in conf file.

I also tried by keeping `allow_anonymous false` and `password_file C:\mosquitto\password.txt` as commented out in conf file and connecting without username and password but no luck.

I have read the conf file and some articles but can't understand the concept of Listeners in conf file but I have a hunch that this is where the configuring needs to be done. If yes, please tell me how to. Any help would be really great.

**Edit:**
I installed the windows 64 bit version from [here](https://mosquitto.org/download/) and am running it as a service. I am using the default conf file and only updated it to add `allow_anonymous false` and `password_file C:\mosquitto\password.txt`. I stopped and started the service after conf file edits.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71428318/edit) the question to show the full `mosquitto.conf` file you are using. Also give it's windows explain how you are running mossquitto and if as a service if you restarted the service after editing the file.

Comment: @hardillb made the edit as asked. Don't have access to the EC2 instance right now so cant post the `mosquitto.conf` file.